# DB first navigation property collection not being generated

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

The entity for this new table gets a ClaimsPortalPreApprovalExplanation.Claim property, but ClaimPortalClaim does not get ClaimsPortalPreApprovalExplanations

```
create table dbo.ClaimsPortalPreApprovalExplanation
(
    ExplanationId int identity,
    Label         varchar(100),
    Value         varchar(25),
    ClaimId       int not null
        constraint ClaimsPortalRepairPreApprovalExplanation_ClaimsPortalClaim_ClaimId_fk
            references dbo.ClaimsPortalClaim,
    RepairId      int
        constraint ClaimsPortalRepairPreApprovalExplanation_ClaimsPortalRepair_RepairId_fk
            references dbo.ClaimsPortalRepair
)
```

This table existed before this new table and works properly.  ClaimsPortalClaim gets a ClaimsPortalRepairs like I want it to.

```
create table dbo.ClaimsPortalRepair
(
    RepairId            int identity
        constraint ClaimPart_pk
            primary key nonclustered,
    PartId              int
        constraint Repair_Part_PartId_fk
            references dbo.Part,
    ClaimId             int                                             not null
        constraint Repair_Claim_ClaimId_fk
            references dbo.ClaimsPortalClaim,
    ...
)
```

Both these tables reference ClaimsPortalClaim by ID with fk.

When I scaffold the entities, ClaimsPortalClaim has a ClaimsPortalRepair[] property but not a ClaimsPortalPreApprovalExplanation[].  Why is that?

Comment: Does your `dbo.ClaimsPortalPreApprovalExplanation` have a primary key (I don't see such in the post)?